# Python empty numpy 2D array and append value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

**Problem**

I wanna make size undefined 2D empty numpy array and append values.

**my try**

```
import numpy as np
import randrom

unknown = random.randint(2, 666)

#arr = np.array([np.array([])])
#arr = np.empty((unknown, 0), int)


for ch in range (unknown):
    some_input = random.randint(1, 666)
    #arr[ch] = np.append((arr[ch], some_input))
    #arr[ch] = np.concatenate((arr[ch], some_input))
    #arr = np.append((arr, some_input), axis=ch)
    #arr = np.concatenate((arr, some_input), axis=ch)
```

none of them works.

You may suggest make axis-wise arrays and combined them into single np array but I cannot do that.

the values must be appended by one by one.

if the unknown value became big and multiple for loops exist outside our for loop then the computer memory cannot handle it.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do with a minimal example please? To create an empty 10x5 2D array, use `arr = np.full((10, 5), np.nan)`

Comment: What are the expected results should look like?

Comment: @Corralien Suppose we know the size of first dimension but second is not defined, and going to append many inputs depends on the first dimension

Comment: @Guy
expecetd
arr[2].append(somevalue)
arr[3].append(somevalue2)
but the arr is empty and size is dynamically moves

Comment: Initialize `arr` as an empty list like `arr = []`, then do the append after loop convert arr to numpy array ?

Comment: @HMH1013 yes but the array should be 2D

Comment: Don't try to intimate a list method with a arrays!  Make your list (of lists), and make the array once, at the end.  This approach has come up dozen of times on SO (:

Comment: `empty` is a list concept.  Don't mistake the `np.empty` function for the same thing.

Comment: if you want to repeatedly (and inefficiently) `concatenate` `(1,666)` shapes in `axis=0`, you need to start with a (0,666) shape.  At each step you'll have a (n,666) shape that copies to a (n+1,666) shape.  No magic, just accurate tracking of shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try a straight forward list append approach to building an array.  This does one array build at the end:

```
In [82]: res=[]
    ...: for i in range(10):
    ...:     res.append(np.arange(20))
    ...: arr = np.array(res)

In [83]: arr.shape
Out[83]: (10, 20)

In [84]: %%timeit
    ...: res=[]
    ...: for i in range(10):
    ...:     res.append(np.arange(20))
    ...: arr = np.array(res)
29.7 µs ± 73.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Now try a numpy approach that tries to immitate the list, making an "empty" start array, and copying it to a new one with each new row.  Note that I have to match the dimensions carefully.  There's less room for being sloppy with this approach:

```
In [85]: res = np.zeros((0,20),int)
    ...: for i in range(10):
    ...:     res = np.concatenate((res, np.arange(20)[None,:]), axis=0)
    ...:     

In [86]: res.shape
Out[86]: (10, 20)

In [87]: %%timeit
    ...: res = np.zeros((0,20),int)
    ...: for i in range(10):
    ...:     res = np.concatenate((res, np.arange(20)[None,:]), axis=0)
119 µs ± 398 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

It's quite a bit slower. Each concatenate (or np.append) requires a full array copy.  Lists are designed to grow, arrays are not.

Each concatenate joins a (n,20) array and a (1,20) to make a new (n+1, 20) array.

The array clone is harder to get right, and slower.  Don't do it.

An alternative is to start off with a (10,20) shape array, and assign each row.  Better yet use a mix of whole-array methods to make the array without any itertions.

---

A variation on the list approach, using a list comprehension to make a list of arrays, and one concatenate call to join them into one:

```
In [88]: np.concatenate([np.arange(20)[None,:] for _ in range(10)], axis=0).shape
Out[88]: (10, 20)

In [89]: timeit np.concatenate([np.arange(20)[None,:] for _ in range(10)], axis=0).shape
43.7 µs ± 180 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you right, you want an empty array that would grow at run time. Assuming the data you append is length k and you run in n times, you will get a n x k matrix. So this can be done by

```
k = 2
X = np.empty((0, k))
X = np.append(X, np.array([[69, 69]]),axis=0)
X = np.append(X,[[420,420]], axis=0)
X = np.append(X,[[42069,42069]], axis=0)
X = np.append(X,[[69420,69420]], axis=0)
```

This will give an an output of

```
array([[   69,    69],
       [  420,   420],
       [42069, 42069],
       [69420, 69420]])
```

Comment: ok what if the axis direction is different?
like

k = 2
X = np.empty((0, k))
X = np.append(X, np.array([[69, 69]]),axis=0)
X = np.append(X,[[420,420]], axis=2)
X = np.append(X,[[42069,42069]], axis=3)
X = np.append(X,[[69420,69420]], axis=4)

Comment: The axis should be the same. What axis=0 does is in which direction to append. You will want to append by increasing the rows. Think of it as, since we have (0,k), we will want the first number to increase and k to remain same. Thats why is it 0.